# How to split HTML string by paragraph

Tags: c#, html

I have an HTML string as shown below

```
<p  style="font-family: Times New Roman;"><span class="cs5efed22f1">HARRISBURG - gov today issued a consumer alert about an apparent scam concerning the Affordable Care Act. In recent days, people across the country have received calls asking for personal information, in order to obtain a "national medical card" from the government. No such card exists.</span>
</p>
<p  style="font-family: Times New Roman;"><span class="cs5efed22f1">"Do not ever give out personal, health care or bank account information over the phone, unless you initiated the call and you know who is on the other end," said Kane.</span>
</p>
<p  style="font-family: Times New Roman;"><span class="cs5efed22f1">Kane says if someone calls, offering to help you obtain this nonexistent national medical card, you should call the AG's Health Care Hotline at (877) 888-4877.  Any information you can provide-- such as the name, telephone number, or location of the caller-- will be very helpful.</span>
</p>
<p ><span  class="cs5efed22f1"><span style="font-family: Times New Roman;">You can learn more about this (and other scams) by visiting the gov's website at</span>
    <a href="http://www.example.org/"><span class="cs61a9f7db1" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255); font-family: Times New Roman;">http://www.example.org</span>
    </a><span style="font-family: Times New Roman;">.</span></span>
</p>
<p ><span class="cs5efed22f1"><span style="font-family: Times New Roman;">The Health Care Section of the test General's website can be found here:</span>
    <a href="http://www.example.org/complaints.aspx?id=458"><span class="cs61a9f7db1" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255); font-family: Times New Roman;">http://www.example.org/complaints.aspx?id=458</span>
    </a>
    </span>
</p>
```

Is need to put some extra HTML after the first paragraph by C#.

How can I split the HTML string based on **p** tag and insert some more HTML after the first or second paragraph?

Comment: Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I don't need to use html agility pack?Is there any way to do this by regx in or any other way in c#?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `yourHtmlString.IndexOf("</p>")` which will give you the index of the first occurence of `</p>`, and then use this index inside of `yourHtmlString.Insert()`

Comment: But what about `<p >` or `<p class="foo">`, and all the other variants? The HTML you see in the real world can be very messy.

Comment: @JimMischel: He only said, that he want's to input something after the first paragraph. Let's not complicate something, that is simple, we can extend that later if needed. ;)

Comment: But his example clearly shows both `<p >` and `<p style="....">`. The complication is already there.